How to make that when keyboard appears it pushes message (tableView content) up?
As in iMessage for example, when keyboard appears, I want to push messages up also. Please help
I've tried put tableView bottomAnchor to backdrop top. But it's not as I want. Messages should be behind backdrop and keyboard. It means tableView bottom anchored to view bottom. Because I need blur effect.
import UIKit
import CoreData
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var titleText: String?
    var country: String?
    var category: String?
    var messageType: String = "general"
    var messages: [Message] = []
    
    private var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private let backdrop: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .prominent)
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private let textField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        textField.setLeftPaddingPoints(10)
        textField.setRightPaddingPoints(10)
        return textField
    }()
    
    private lazy var sendButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "paperplane.fill"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        setupTableView()
        setupInputComponents()
        setupConstraints()
        
        if let titleText = titleText {
            self.title = titleText
        }
        
        fetchMessages()
        listenForMessages()
    }
    
    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(MessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MessageCell.identifier)
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 55, right: 0)
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
    
    private func setupInputComponents() {
        view.addSubview(backdrop)
        backdrop.contentView.addSubview(textField)
        backdrop.contentView.addSubview(sendButton)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
            view.keyboardLayoutGuide.usesBottomSafeArea = false
            view.keyboardLayoutGuide.keyboardDismissPadding = 50
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow: textField.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdrop.bottomAnchor),
                view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: textField.bottomAnchor),
            
                tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                
                backdrop.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                backdrop.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                backdrop.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                
                textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdrop.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
                textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdrop.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -8),
                textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: backdrop.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36),
                
                sendButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
                sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdrop.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
                sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.centerYAnchor),
                sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
                sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            ])
        }
    
    @objc private func sendButtonTapped() {
        guard let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty else { return }

        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            print("No user is currently logged in")
            return
        }

        let senderId = currentUser.uid
        let receiverId: String? = messageType == "private" ? "specialistId" : nil
        let messageId = UUID().uuidString
        let timestamp = Date()

        // Fetch user details using UserProfileManager
        UserProfileManager.shared.fetchUserProfile(uid: senderId) { [weak self] user in
            guard let self = self else { return }
//            guard let user = user else {
//                print("Failed to fetch user details from Core Data or Firestore")
//                return
//            }
            
            // Save to Firestore
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let messageData: [String: Any] = [
                "id": messageId,
                "senderId": senderId,
                "receiverId": receiverId ?? "",
                "text": text,
                "messageType": self.messageType,
                "country": self.country ?? "",
                "category": self.category ?? "",
                "timestamp": timestamp
            ]
            db.collection("messages").document(messageId).setData(messageData) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error saving message to Firestore: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Message saved to Firestore")
                }
            }

            // Save to Core Data
            CoreDataHelper.shared.saveMessage(
                id: messageId,
                senderId: senderId,
                receiverId: receiverId,
                text: text,
                messageType: self.messageType,
                country: self.country,
                category: self.category,
                timestamp: timestamp
            )

            self.textField.text = ""
            self.fetchMessages()
            self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchMessages() {
        messages = CoreDataHelper.shared.fetchMessages(country: country, category: category)
        tableView.reloadData()
        scrollToBottom(animated: false)
    }
    
    private func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
        guard messages.count > 0 else { return }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
    }
    
    private func listenForMessages() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("messages").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents in snapshot")
                return
            }
            
            var newMessages: [Message] = []
            for document in documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let id = data["id"] as! String
                if !CoreDataHelper.shared.messageExists(id: id) {
                    let senderId = data["senderId"] as! String
                    let receiverId = data["receiverId"] as? String
                    let text = data["text"] as! String
                    let messageType = data["messageType"] as! String
                    let country = data["country"] as? String
                    let category = data["category"] as? String
                    let timestamp = (data["timestamp"] as! Timestamp).dateValue()
                    
                    let message = Message(context: CoreDataHelper.shared.context)
                    message.id = id
                    message.senderId = senderId
                    message.receiverId = receiverId
                    message.text = text
                    message.messageType = messageType
                    message.country = country
                    message.category = category
                    message.timestamp = timestamp
                    newMessages.append(message)
                }
            }
            
            CoreDataHelper.shared.syncMessages(with: newMessages)
            self.fetchMessages()
            self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    // UITableViewDataSource methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MessageCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return cell
        }
        let isCurrentUser = message.senderId == currentUser.uid
        cell.configure(with: message, isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser)
        return cell
    }
    
    // UITableViewDelegate methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        let size = CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width * 0.75, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: message.text ?? "").boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        let height = estimatedFrame.height + 40 // Padding and name label height
        return height
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
    func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
        self.rightView = paddingView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}

